# Adding multiple attachments to email sent through Windows command line

Tags: windows, email, batch-file, command-line, email-attachments

Is there a way to do this? I can easily add multiple email recipients but haven't been able to specify multiple attachments in any similar way.

The code format I'm currently using is:

"[...]\outlook.exe" /a "[...].txt" /m "[recipient1]; [recipient2]&subject=[subject]&body=[body]"

To add a second attachment, I've tried adding semicolons, commas, removing the quotations and just listing the filepaths, adding the second filepath in quotations, etc., all with no luck. Is it possible at all to do this?

Comment: Have you tried simply adding multiple `/a` switches, that is, `/a att1.txt /a att2.txt /a att3.txt ...`?

Answer (score 2):

You can send multiple attachments from the command line or .bat file.

```
powershell send-mailmessage -to 'pwatson@dom.org' -from 'pwatson@dom.org' ^
  -subject 'Multiple email attachments' ^
  -SmtpServer 'mail.dom.org' ^
  -attachment f1.txt, f2.txt, f3.txt
```